# SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser

Tags: spservices

I'm using this great tool to fill some of the fields in my list. It works great when I do this one by one, but I'm trying to request multiple column values, but I can't get it to work.

```
var thisUsersValues = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
fieldNames: ["ID", "Name", "SIP Address"],
debug: false
});
```

How can I get specific column value (e.g. "Name") using this way?

Comment: Similar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043403/spservices-getcurrentuser-write-variable-into-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the individual values with the following:

```
var name = thisUsersValues["Name"];

var ID = thisUsersValues["ID"];

var SIPAddress = thisUsersValues["SIP Address"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using fieldNames, just use fieldname.

```
$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
  fieldName: "Name",
  debug: false
});
```

Or using your current function it'd be this I believe:

```
var thisUsersValues = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
fieldNames: ["ID", "Name", "SIP Address"],
debug: false
});
var name = thisUsersValues[1];
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I tried just using fieldName:"Name", and it worked, but I'll need to pull the info for several fields (e.g. Email, title, etc, etc.), so I don't want to do them one by one. That's why I used the second version. I also tried before what you proposed "thisUsersValues[1]" and it didn't work, get an 'undefined" message.

Comment: I'm not in a position to dive into it fully atm. Console log out thisUsersValues and see what it returns, I thought it was an array, he might be returning an object.

Answer (score 3):

Since `SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser()` function returns an associative array where the keys are mapped to `fieldNames` you could access it as:

```
var name = thisUserValues.Name;
```

or

```
var name = thisUserValues['Name'];
```

Comment: thanks. Your answer also is correct, but unfortunately i can only mark one response as an answer, and i don't have 15 Reputation to give you at least "point" for helpful answer.